# symfony monolog writing logs to different files according to channels

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony app I am using monolog to log errors and I got different channels. I need to write different channels to different files. I got the following monolog config:

```
//app\config\config.yml
monolog:
channels: ['my_channel', 'my_channel2']
use_microseconds: false
handlers:
    file:
        type:   stream
        path:   %kernel.logs_dir%/prod_info.log
        level:  info
        channels: [!my_channel2]
    file_2:
        type:   stream
        path:   %kernel.logs_dir%/mylogfile_2.log
        level:  info
        channels: [my_channel2]
    file_errors:
        type:   stream
        path:   %kernel.logs_dir%/cms_errors.log
        level:  error
        channels: [!my_channel2]
```

my config.prod config

```
monolog:
handlers:
    main:
        type:         fingers_crossed
        action_level: debug
        handler:      nested
        channels: [!my_channel2]
    nested:
        type:  stream
        path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/main_%kernel.environment%.log"
        level: debug
        channels: [!my_channel2]
    console:
        type:  console
```

I can access `my_channel2` in the code like this:

```
$logger = $this->get('monolog.logger.my_channel2');
$logger->debug('Some message here');
```

but still all `my_channel2` messages are written to `main_prod.log` file instead of `mylogfile_2.log`. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just needed to change action level from info to debug for the required channel

```
file_2:
    type:   stream
    path:   %kernel.logs_dir%/mylogfile_2.log
    level:  debug // <== change from info to debug here
    channels: [my_channel2]
```